# Javascript/jquery methods not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two JavaScript methods that receive parameters that are used to set the values of input tags that are in forms. For some reason the methods don't submit those forms when using the jquery submit method.

The jsp code:
This form is for a delete button.

```
<form action="<c:url value='DelPCest'/>"  method="post" name="Cesto">
    <input type="hidden" name="ProId" value=""/>
    <input type="button" value="Remover"
        onclick="DelPL(${ListaPro.getProduct().getPid()}, ${Ls})" />
</form>
```

This form is for a update button

```
<form name="CestoAcc" action="<c:url value='Atual'/>" method="post"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="ProNum" value=""/>
    <input type="button" value="Actualizar"
        onclick="ActP(${ListaPro.getProduct().getPid()})" />
</form>
```

The getPid() method return a integer.

The javaScript code:

This for delete button

```
function DelPL(ProId,Qel){
    jConfirm('Eliminar o Produto do Cesto?', 'Confirmação', function(r) {
        if (r == true) {
            if (Qel == 1) {
                jAlert('info', 'O cesto vai ficar sem produtos', 'INFORMAÇÃO', function(f) {
                    if (f == true) {
                        jConfirm('Quer eliminar o produto?', 'Confirmação', function(f){
                            if (f == true) {
                                $("input[name='ProId']").val(ProId);
                                $("form[name='Cesto']").submit();       
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $("input[name='ProId']").val(ProId);
                $("form[name='Cesto']").submit();
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

This for the update button

```
function ActP(ProNum) {
    jConfirm('Actualizar?', 'CONFRIMAÇÃO', function(r) {
        if (r == true) {
            $("input[name='ProNum']").val(ProNum);
            //document.CestoAcc.submit();
            $("form[name='CestoAcc']").submit();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

NOTE: This are the only methods that don't submit to the servelt.

Comment: content of the post is ambiguous i cant get the flow then how to assume where the error would be?

Comment: @HemantMetalia couldn't have said it better myself

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an `id` to the form : `<form id="Cesto"...` and then calling the submit like this: `$("#Cesto").submit();`. Also check to make sure there are not javascipt error in your browers error console. If there are any errors then any code after the error will not execute.